# Does a widow 1st nikah will be finish after her husband died?

Tags: hadith

Assalamu Alekum Wrb,

I want to know that a widow 1st nikah will be finish after her husband died or she needs to take a qula before 2nd nikah to be perform. kindly tell me as i want to marry her.

Jazak Allah Khair

Comment: What is qula? All she needs is to wait until her waiting period ends.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Or if she is pregnant and her husband dies while she is pregnant then her waiting period end when she gives birth.

Comment: @Arnaan that is included in the definition of the waiting period ('idah).

Answer (score 1):

A widow can remarry after her husband's death and after observing a [waiting period](https://islamqa.info/en/101546) (iddah). There is no Khula or Talaq, since they are given by the husband (who is dead), nor a need for Fask from a Judge etc.

> [Quran 2:234](https://quran.com/2/234) **And those who are taken in death among you and leave
>   wives behind** - they, [the wives, shall] wait four months and ten
>   [days]. And when they have fulfilled their term, t**hen there is no
>   blame upon you for what they do with themselves in an acceptable
>   manner**. And Allah is [fully] Acquainted with what you do.

You can not make a nikah with her during her mourning period, and you shouldn't make an explicit proposal during that period either, but you are permitted to leave a hint indirectly:

> [Quran 2:235](https://quran.com/2/235) There is no blame upon you for that to which you
>   [indirectly] allude concerning a proposal to women or for what you
>   conceal within yourselves. Allah knows that you will have them in
>   mind. **But do not promise them secretly except for saying a proper
>   saying.** **And do not determine to undertake a marriage contract until
>   the decreed period reaches its end.** And know that Allah knows what is
>   within yourselves, so beware of Him. And know that Allah is Forgiving
>   and Forbearing.

For details see [Tafsir Ibn Kathir](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=157).